# Google form: Can I add a hyper link that will be opened on a new tab?

Tags: google-forms, google-form-quiz

I have no idea how to add a hyperlink (that will be opened on a new tab) in a Google form. I know how to do in HTML but I don't know how to do in a Google form.

I have just added a link in the "Confirmation message:" of presentation area of the Google form settings.

[image: settings]

...

[image: image02]

*I think this HTML code cannot be applied to a Google form: (target="_blank")*

https://forms.gle/AGz1ngWM7fZXLJkv7

In order to link to another Google form after submitting the quiz, I would like to add the link that can access this other Google form before/after viewing the quiz results. But if I click on the link for this other Google form before/after viewing the quiz in the current tab, I cannot go back to viewing the quiz results.

If it is not applicable to add a link that will be opened on a new tab, it is acceptable to add a link in the quiz results. However, I have no idea how to add a link in the quiz results page.

This is a demo of my quiz form: https://forms.gle/rKrcSh1aGVAeY4sR7

Answer (score 2):

> *...I have no idea how to add a link in the quiz results page*

You cannot.

#### Fortunately there is a workaround

You can create a **small script in the spreadsheet** that will send an email to the submitter upon submission of the form.

- Go to `Tools` -> `Script editor...`
- When in the script editor, erase all the presented code and replace it with the following:

**The code**:

```
// Email the submitter including a HYPER-LINK

function Hyper2Them(e){
  var theirFirst = e.values[4];
  var theirLast = e.values[5];
  var theirEmail = e.values[1];
  var myEmail = "myemail@xyz.com";
  var theQuiz = e.values[3];
  var subject = "About your Quiz: " + theQuiz;
  var message = " Your current EMAIL is: " + theirEmail + "\n To: " + theirLast + " \n\n Dear: " + theirFirst + " \n We will be sending you an EMAIL with your results from: " + theQuiz + " \n Till then please follow instructions found on this address: https://www.google.gr/ "; 
  
  MailApp.sendEmail (theirEmail, subject, message);
}
```

- Save
- Authorize
- Now click on the clock icon on the toolbar and on the new page, set up a trigger for `On form submit` and save the trigger.

[image: hyper trigger]

- Test and Enjoy!

#### Notes

The `e.values` 1, 2, and so on, correspond to the columns on the spreadsheet where the answers are submitted. Keep in mind that the numbering for the columns start with 0. (*Zero being the column reserved for the timestamp*.)

*You can read all about limitations on Google accounts and triggers at: [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) and [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround:

Each form has a linked spreadsheet.

Add a sheet with your link or links to this spreadsheet and publish it to the web.

Place the link to the published spreadsheet into the Confirmation message. Moreover you can use formatting on this page.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight two step workaround for this. Thinking outside of the box... If you have a public webpage / website (if not note you can use a public blogger page for free), you can create a page and add a hyperlink that opens into a new window using either the page WYSIWYG editor or html code. Once the page is ready, in the Google Form "Confirmation Message" you can add the full URL of that page to the message. Note you MUST include the http:// or https:// because this will then open the page within the same iframe as the Google form. If you do not add http it will not load! Within that iframe the form submitter will then view the page you created and when they click the link in that page it will open into a new window. Use common sense. In the "Confirmation Message" tell the submitter what to do, for example, "Click the following links to go to the next section".